# "Execute and Update '# =>' Markers" for VIM

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins, textmate

Is there a possibility in VIM to repeat "Execute and Update '# =>' Markers" TextMate feature for ruby code.

I'd like to have something like:

```
x = 2
class A
  def a
    42
  end
end

x # => 
A.new.a # =>
```

Enter some command... and get

```
x = 2
class A
  def a
    42
  end
end

x # => 2
A.new.a # => 42
```

Here is a description of this feature from [Ciarán Walsh’s Blog](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/02/20/textmate-tip-the-ruby-bundle):

> Another tool definitely worth knowing
>   is the "Execute and Update '# =>'
>   Markers" command (on ⌃⇧⌘E by default).
>   To use it, add some comment markers
>   (there is a snippet on #⇥ that will
>   insert these for you) to the end of
>   lines you would like to see the
>   results of and then trigger the
>   command. TextMate will run your code
>   and report the result of the marked
>   line inline in the comments. This
>   feature is great for code posted
>   online since it shows the source and
>   the results together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xmpfilter` from [rcodetools](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcodetools).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it shouldn't be too hard to write this as a Vim function.  Try this:

```
function! ExecuteAndUpdate()
    ruby << EOF
        marker = '# =>'
        buf = VIM::Buffer.current
        lines = File.readlines(buf.name)

        bnd = binding
        eval(lines.join("\n"), bnd)

        lines.each_with_index do |line, i|
            if line.match(/#{marker}/)
                result = marker + ' ' + eval(line, bnd).inspect
                buf[i+1] = line.sub(/#{marker}.*/, result).chomp
            end
        end
EOF
endfunction
```

Then `:call ExecuteAndUpdate()`.

One limitation is that it evaluates each line with a marker twice.  So lines with markers shouldn't have side-effects.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be another limitation I guess.